# Never did I see her again

Tags: inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion, negative-inversion

> a. Never again did I see her.
> b. Never did I see her again.

I'd use (a) over (b). But is (b) natural? If so, is there any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'natural' way to say it is "I never saw her again". Putting *never* at the beginning is a literary/formal way to emphasise the word. The difference between (a) and (b) is a matter of opinion; I think I would favour (a).

Comment: Thanks. If both work and there's no difference in meaning, why would you favor (a)?

Comment: I consider it stylistically better, but opinion-based questions are off-topic.

Comment: How would you know for sure if it's opinion based? If most native speakers, not just you, favor (a), wouldn't (a) be simply more idiomatic than (b)?

Comment: Well, putting _never_ at the beginning would only occur in consciously 'poetic' language anyway. Others are welcome to comment.

Answer (score -2):

If a sentence begins from a negative adverb there must be the inversion. The first one is only correct because negative adverb stays first in the sentence. If you want to avoid inversion just use it in other place in a sentence

Comment: This is irrelevant, since both examples have the verb inverted.

Comment: Ok then both are correct and it's an official style

Comment: @PetroProbka If you have changed your mind and now think your answer is wrong, then you should probably edit or delete it.